# Matlab parfor + multi-processing

Tags: matlab, parfor

I am trying to run some code that creates a sketch from an image:
https://github.com/panly099/sketchSynthesis
After getting it going on windows, im running into what I think are performance issues. The program is supposed to complete the task in 5 minutes, but my computer wont complete the task at all (ive waited at least 30 minutes)
I got some advice that I need to look into "parfor" and multiprocessing to speed it up/get it to complete the task.
Im wondering if someone could explain it to me simply how I might be able to speed it up to complete the image in under 5 minutes.
The code im supposed to edit is:
https://github.com/panly099/sketchSynthesis/blob/master/functions/sketchDetect.m

```
  function [ detection ] = sketchDetect(sample, strokeModel, configurations, searchRatio, threshold, appGeoWeight)
% This function anchors the stroke model on the given input sketch or edge
% map sample via a dynamic programming process.
%   Input :
%       sample : the input sketch or edge map sample.
%       strokeModel : the stroke model.
%       configurations : the sampled configurations of the object.
%       searchRatio : the search ratio of the original stroke bounding box.
%       threshold : the chamfer matching threshold.
%       appGeoWeight : the balance between the appearance and the geometry.
%   Output :
%       detection : the detected model instance.
%   Author :
%       panly099@gmail.com
%   Version :
%       1.1 07/06/2016

if nargin < 5
    threshold = 0.5;
end
if nargin < 6
    appGeoWeight = 0.5;
end

baseScale = 1;
baseAspect = 1;
overlapWeight = 0.001;

mst = strokeModel.mst;
avgWidth = strokeModel.avgWidth;
avgHeight = strokeModel.avgHeight;
clusterBbox = strokeModel.clusterBbox;

[height, width] = size(sample);
numConf = length(configurations);
detections = cell(1, numConf);
energy = zeros(1,numConf);

for a = 1 : numConf
    configuration = configurations{a};
    %% sampling by fast directional chamfer matching (fdcm)
    numCluster = length(configuration);
    strokeCandidates = cell(1, numCluster);

    parfor j = 1 : numCluster
        fprintf('current stroke id: %d\n', j);
        strokeImg = configuration{j};

        strBbox = getBoundingBox(strokeImg,0);
        strokeImg = strokeImg(strBbox(2):strBbox(4), strBbox(1):strBbox(3));

        % compute the search region
        curBbox = clusterBbox(:,j)';
        %         curBbox = strBbox;
        curWidth = curBbox(3) - curBbox(1);
        curHeight = curBbox(4) - curBbox(2);
        searchRegion = [curBbox(1) - ceil((searchRatio - 1) / 2 * curWidth), curBbox(2) - ceil((searchRatio - 1) / 2 * curHeight), ...
            curBbox(3) + ceil((searchRatio - 1) / 2 * curWidth), curBbox(4) + ceil((searchRatio - 1) / 2 * curHeight)];
        if searchRegion(1) < 1
            searchRegion(1) = 1;
        end
        if searchRegion(2) < 1
            searchRegion(2) = 1;
        end
        if searchRegion(3) > width
            searchRegion(3) = width;
        end
        if searchRegion(4) > height
            searchRegion(4) = height;
        end

        img = sample(searchRegion(2):searchRegion(4), searchRegion(1):searchRegion(3));

        % fdcm anchoring
        [strokeMatched, cost] = chamferLocate(img, strokeImg, baseScale, baseAspect, threshold);


        %                 figure;imshow(~strokeImg);figure;imshow(~img);
        if size(strokeMatched,1) > 1000
            stop = 1;
        end
        for s = 1 : length(strokeMatched)
            tmpSample = zeros(height, width);
            tmpSample(searchRegion(2):searchRegion(4), searchRegion(1):searchRegion(3)) = strokeMatched{s};

            if cost(s) <= 0
                cost(s) = 1;
            end
            strokeCandidates{j}(s,:) = [{tmpSample}, cost(s)];
            %                          figure;imshow(~strokeMatched{s});

        end

        %         figure;imshow(sample);
    end

    %% energy minimization by dynamic programming
    % backward
    fprintf('Backward propogation\n');
    for i = length(mst) : -1 : 2
        fprintf('Scanning MST layer: %d\n', i);
        curLayer = mst{i};
        for j = 1 : length(curLayer)
%             parents = [];
            curEdge = curLayer{j};
            curParent = curEdge{1}(2);
%             parents = [parents curParent];
            curChild = curEdge{1}(1);
            curParam = curEdge{2};

            curParentChildIdx = size(strokeCandidates{curParent},2) + 1;
            curParentCandidates = strokeCandidates{curParent}(:,1);
            curChildCandidates = strokeCandidates{curChild};

            for p = 1 : length(curParentCandidates)
                tmpBbox = getBoundingBox(curParentCandidates{p}, 0);
                curParentCenter = ceil([(tmpBbox(2)+tmpBbox(4))/2, (tmpBbox(1)+tmpBbox(3))/2]);

                childCosts = ones(1, size(curChildCandidates, 1))*Inf;
                for c = 1 : size(curChildCandidates, 1)
                    tmpBbox = getBoundingBox(curChildCandidates{c,1},0);
                    curChildCenter = ceil([(tmpBbox(2)+tmpBbox(4))/2, (tmpBbox(1)+tmpBbox(3))/2]);
                    geoNorm = 1/40;
                    curCost = appGeoWeight * curChildCandidates{c,2} - (1-appGeoWeight) * geoNorm * log(mvnpdf(curChildCenter-curParentCenter, ...
                        curParam{2},curParam{3}));

                    for gc = 3 : size(curChildCandidates,2)
                        curCost = curCost + curChildCandidates{c,gc}(2);
                    end

                    childCosts(c) = curCost;
                end
                [minCost, minIdx] = min(childCosts);
                if minCost == Inf
                    stop = 1;
                end
                strokeCandidates{curParent}{p, curParentChildIdx} = [curChild, minCost, minIdx];
            end

%             % adding overlapping penalty
%             parents = unique(parents);
%             for u = 1 : length(parents)
%                 curParent = parents(u);
%                 for p = 1 : size(strokeCandidates{curParent}, 1)
%                     curParentImg = strokeCandidates{curParent}{p,1};
%                     overlapCost = 0;
%                     for c = 3 : size(strokeCandidates{curParent}, 2)
%                         curChild = strokeCandidates{curParent}{p,c}(1);
%                         curChildIdx = strokeCandidates{curParent}{p,c}(3);
%                         curChildImg = strokeCandidates{curChild}{curChildIdx,1};
%                         curOverlap = curParentImg.*curChildImg;
%                         overlapCost = overlapCost + sum(curOverlap(:)) * overlapWeight;
%                     end
%                     strokeCandidates{curParent}{p,2} = strokeCandidates{curParent}{p,2} + overlapCost;
%                 end
%             end
        end
    end

    % forward
    fprintf('forward propogation\n');
    fprintf('Scanning MST layer: %d\n', 1);
    detection = cell(1, numCluster);
    root = mst{1};

    rootCosts = [];
    for i = 1 : size(strokeCandidates{root},1)
        cost = strokeCandidates{root}{i,2};
        for j = 3 : size(strokeCandidates{root},2)
            cost = cost + strokeCandidates{root}{i,j}(2);
        end
        rootCosts(end+1) = cost;
    end
    [~,rootSelected] = min(rootCosts);
    minCost = rootCosts(rootSelected);

    detection{root} = strokeCandidates{root}{rootSelected, 1};

    for i = 2 : length(mst)
        fprintf('Scanning MST layer: %d\n', i);
        curLayer = mst{i};

        for j = 1 : length(curLayer)
            curEdge = curLayer{j};
            curParent = curEdge{1}(2);
            curChild = curEdge{1}(1);
            curParam = curEdge{2};

            curParentCandidate = detection{curParent};
            curChildCandidates = strokeCandidates{curChild};

            tmpBbox = getBoundingBox(curParentCandidate, 0);
            curParentCenter = ceil([(tmpBbox(2)+tmpBbox(4))/2, (tmpBbox(1)+tmpBbox(3))/2]);

            childCosts = ones(1, size(curChildCandidates, 1))*Inf;
            for c = 1 : size(curChildCandidates, 1)
                tmpBbox = getBoundingBox(curChildCandidates{c,1},0);
                curChildCenter = ceil([(tmpBbox(2)+tmpBbox(4))/2, (tmpBbox(1)+tmpBbox(3))/2]);

                geoNorm = 1/40;
                curCost = appGeoWeight * curChildCandidates{c,2} - (1-appGeoWeight) * geoNorm * log(mvnpdf(curChildCenter-curParentCenter, ...
                    curParam{2},curParam{3}));

                for gc = 3 : size(curChildCandidates,2)
                    curCost = curCost + curChildCandidates{c,gc}(2);
                end

                childCosts(c) = curCost;
            end
            [~, minId] = min(childCosts);
            detection{curChild} = curChildCandidates{minId,1};
        end
    end


    detections{a} = detection;
    energy(a) = minCost;

end
[~,minIdx] = min(energy);
detection = detections{minIdx};

% visualize the detection
% synthesized = zeros(height, width);
% for i = 1 : length(detection)
%     if sum(detection{i}(:))>1
%         synthesized = synthesized + detection{i};
%     end
% end
% figure;imshow(~sample);
% figure;imshow(~synthesized);

end
```

Comment: If you can't even *link* to any specific code when asking for performance improvements then this is definitely too broad for SO, given that preferably you'd post a [mcve] *within the question*. Please read [ask] and make your question more answerable. You can't just throw a `parfor` at a performance issue and hope it goes away, there might be a million other factors at play. Try to [profile](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/profile.html) and [debug](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/debugging-process-and-features.html) your code to find the specific bottlenecks first.

Comment: I've edited the question now. I wasnt sure where it was in the plethora of code of this project.

Comment: Profile the code to see where is the bottleneck. Also parfor *can* speed up your code but also it can not. depends on the code. Generally it just needs the outermost loop to be replaced by `parfor` instead of `for`. If you need more than that, then you need to really really learn it

Comment: Thanks. How do I profile the code if the code doesnt run until after I choose the image in the image opener window?

Comment: You can run the code line by line, see which bits take the most time, which bits are taking ages...

Comment: @JerryWorger you can use the profiler [via commands in your script](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/profile.html).

Comment: I've moved the question to: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49618724/parallel-computing-and-number-of-cores-in-matlab  im thinking its a RAM issue