# Parallel computing and number of cores in Matlab

Tags: matlab, parfor

I am trying to run some code that creates a sketch from an image:
https://github.com/panly099/sketchSynthesis

After getting it going on windows, im running into what I think are performance issues. The program is supposed to complete the task in 5 minutes, but my computer wont complete the task at all (ive waited at least 30 minutes)

My computer has only 4GB of RAM and is an Intel I3.
The code uses parallel computing apparently, so to active Parfor I did:

```
if matlabpool('size') == 0
matlabpool open 2
end
```

Which gave me "connected to 2 workers"

The CPU usage looks like: https://i.stack.imgur.com/fs2T8.jpg

Im wondering if someone could explain it to me simply how I might be able to speed it up to complete the image in under 5 minutes, or tell me if I need to upgrade my RAM or amount of cores.
The guy who wrote the code said he ran it originally on an 8-core server.
The code that includes the parfor loop comes from
https://github.com/panly099/sketchSynthesis/blob/master/functions/sketchDetect.m :

```
function [ detection ] = sketchDetect(sample, strokeModel, configurations, searchRatio, threshold, appGeoWeight)
% This function anchors the stroke model on the given input sketch or edge
% map sample via a dynamic programming process.
%   Input :
%       sample : the input sketch or edge map sample.
%       strokeModel : the stroke model.
%       configurations : the sampled configurations of the object.
%       searchRatio : the search ratio of the original stroke bounding box.
%       threshold : the chamfer matching threshold.
%       appGeoWeight : the balance between the appearance and the geometry.
%   Output :
%       detection : the detected model instance.
%   Author :
%       panly099@gmail.com
%   Version :
%       1.1 07/06/2016

if nargin < 5
    threshold = 0.5;
end
if nargin < 6
    appGeoWeight = 0.5;
end

baseScale = 1;
baseAspect = 1;
overlapWeight = 0.001;

mst = strokeModel.mst;
avgWidth = strokeModel.avgWidth;
avgHeight = strokeModel.avgHeight;
clusterBbox = strokeModel.clusterBbox;

[height, width] = size(sample);
numConf = length(configurations);
detections = cell(1, numConf);
energy = zeros(1,numConf);

for a = 1 : numConf
    configuration = configurations{a};
    %% sampling by fast directional chamfer matching (fdcm)
    numCluster = length(configuration);
    strokeCandidates = cell(1, numCluster);

    parfor j = 1 : numCluster
        fprintf('current stroke id: %d\n', j);
        strokeImg = configuration{j};

        strBbox = getBoundingBox(strokeImg,0);
        strokeImg = strokeImg(strBbox(2):strBbox(4), strBbox(1):strBbox(3));

        % compute the search region
        curBbox = clusterBbox(:,j)';
        %         curBbox = strBbox;
        curWidth = curBbox(3) - curBbox(1);
        curHeight = curBbox(4) - curBbox(2);
        searchRegion = [curBbox(1) - ceil((searchRatio - 1) / 2 * curWidth), curBbox(2) - ceil((searchRatio - 1) / 2 * curHeight), ...
            curBbox(3) + ceil((searchRatio - 1) / 2 * curWidth), curBbox(4) + ceil((searchRatio - 1) / 2 * curHeight)];
        if searchRegion(1) < 1
            searchRegion(1) = 1;
        end
        if searchRegion(2) < 1
            searchRegion(2) = 1;
        end
        if searchRegion(3) > width
            searchRegion(3) = width;
        end
        if searchRegion(4) > height
            searchRegion(4) = height;
        end

        img = sample(searchRegion(2):searchRegion(4), searchRegion(1):searchRegion(3));

        % fdcm anchoring
        [strokeMatched, cost] = chamferLocate(img, strokeImg, baseScale, baseAspect, threshold);


        %                 figure;imshow(~strokeImg);figure;imshow(~img);
        if size(strokeMatched,1) > 1000
            stop = 1;
        end
        for s = 1 : length(strokeMatched)
            tmpSample = zeros(height, width);
            tmpSample(searchRegion(2):searchRegion(4), searchRegion(1):searchRegion(3)) = strokeMatched{s};

            if cost(s) <= 0
                cost(s) = 1;
            end
            strokeCandidates{j}(s,:) = [{tmpSample}, cost(s)];
            %                          figure;imshow(~strokeMatched{s});

        end

        %         figure;imshow(sample);
    end

    %% energy minimization by dynamic programming
    % backward
    fprintf('Backward propogation\n');
    for i = length(mst) : -1 : 2
        fprintf('Scanning MST layer: %d\n', i);
        curLayer = mst{i};
        for j = 1 : length(curLayer)
%             parents = [];
            curEdge = curLayer{j};
            curParent = curEdge{1}(2);
%             parents = [parents curParent];
            curChild = curEdge{1}(1);
            curParam = curEdge{2};

            curParentChildIdx = size(strokeCandidates{curParent},2) + 1;
            curParentCandidates = strokeCandidates{curParent}(:,1);
            curChildCandidates = strokeCandidates{curChild};

            for p = 1 : length(curParentCandidates)
                tmpBbox = getBoundingBox(curParentCandidates{p}, 0);
                curParentCenter = ceil([(tmpBbox(2)+tmpBbox(4))/2, (tmpBbox(1)+tmpBbox(3))/2]);

                childCosts = ones(1, size(curChildCandidates, 1))*Inf;
                for c = 1 : size(curChildCandidates, 1)
                    tmpBbox = getBoundingBox(curChildCandidates{c,1},0);
                    curChildCenter = ceil([(tmpBbox(2)+tmpBbox(4))/2, (tmpBbox(1)+tmpBbox(3))/2]);
                    geoNorm = 1/40;
                    curCost = appGeoWeight * curChildCandidates{c,2} - (1-appGeoWeight) * geoNorm * log(mvnpdf(curChildCenter-curParentCenter, ...
                        curParam{2},curParam{3}));

                    for gc = 3 : size(curChildCandidates,2)
                        curCost = curCost + curChildCandidates{c,gc}(2);
                    end

                    childCosts(c) = curCost;
                end
                [minCost, minIdx] = min(childCosts);
                if minCost == Inf
                    stop = 1;
                end
                strokeCandidates{curParent}{p, curParentChildIdx} = [curChild, minCost, minIdx];
            end

%             % adding overlapping penalty
%             parents = unique(parents);
%             for u = 1 : length(parents)
%                 curParent = parents(u);
%                 for p = 1 : size(strokeCandidates{curParent}, 1)
%                     curParentImg = strokeCandidates{curParent}{p,1};
%                     overlapCost = 0;
%                     for c = 3 : size(strokeCandidates{curParent}, 2)
%                         curChild = strokeCandidates{curParent}{p,c}(1);
%                         curChildIdx = strokeCandidates{curParent}{p,c}(3);
%                         curChildImg = strokeCandidates{curChild}{curChildIdx,1};
%                         curOverlap = curParentImg.*curChildImg;
%                         overlapCost = overlapCost + sum(curOverlap(:)) * overlapWeight;
%                     end
%                     strokeCandidates{curParent}{p,2} = strokeCandidates{curParent}{p,2} + overlapCost;
%                 end
%             end
        end
    end

    % forward
    fprintf('forward propogation\n');
    fprintf('Scanning MST layer: %d\n', 1);
    detection = cell(1, numCluster);
    root = mst{1};

    rootCosts = [];
    for i = 1 : size(strokeCandidates{root},1)
        cost = strokeCandidates{root}{i,2};
        for j = 3 : size(strokeCandidates{root},2)
            cost = cost + strokeCandidates{root}{i,j}(2);
        end
        rootCosts(end+1) = cost;
    end
    [~,rootSelected] = min(rootCosts);
    minCost = rootCosts(rootSelected);

    detection{root} = strokeCandidates{root}{rootSelected, 1};

    for i = 2 : length(mst)
        fprintf('Scanning MST layer: %d\n', i);
        curLayer = mst{i};

        for j = 1 : length(curLayer)
            curEdge = curLayer{j};
            curParent = curEdge{1}(2);
            curChild = curEdge{1}(1);
            curParam = curEdge{2};

            curParentCandidate = detection{curParent};
            curChildCandidates = strokeCandidates{curChild};

            tmpBbox = getBoundingBox(curParentCandidate, 0);
            curParentCenter = ceil([(tmpBbox(2)+tmpBbox(4))/2, (tmpBbox(1)+tmpBbox(3))/2]);

            childCosts = ones(1, size(curChildCandidates, 1))*Inf;
            for c = 1 : size(curChildCandidates, 1)
                tmpBbox = getBoundingBox(curChildCandidates{c,1},0);
                curChildCenter = ceil([(tmpBbox(2)+tmpBbox(4))/2, (tmpBbox(1)+tmpBbox(3))/2]);

                geoNorm = 1/40;
                curCost = appGeoWeight * curChildCandidates{c,2} - (1-appGeoWeight) * geoNorm * log(mvnpdf(curChildCenter-curParentCenter, ...
                    curParam{2},curParam{3}));

                for gc = 3 : size(curChildCandidates,2)
                    curCost = curCost + curChildCandidates{c,gc}(2);
                end

                childCosts(c) = curCost;
            end
            [~, minId] = min(childCosts);
            detection{curChild} = curChildCandidates{minId,1};
        end
    end


    detections{a} = detection;
    energy(a) = minCost;

end
[~,minIdx] = min(energy);
detection = detections{minIdx};

% visualize the detection
% synthesized = zeros(height, width);
% for i = 1 : length(detection)
%     if sum(detection{i}(:))>1
%         synthesized = synthesized + detection{i};
%     end
% end
% figure;imshow(~sample);
% figure;imshow(~synthesized);

end
```

Comment: With only 4GB of RAM you're almost certainly going to grind to a halt using parallel processing.  4GB is really the bare minimum for using 1 MATLAB process.  By using `matlabpool open 2` you will have 3 MATLAB processes (1 client, 2 workers) all trying to use that same 4GB.  You can be sure that the guy who ran it on an 8-core server had way more than 4GB in total and most likely more than 4GB per worker.

Comment: Thanks for the response. How much RAM do you think would be required to speed up the process to 5 minutes without killing the computer? If I upgraded my computer to 8GB would that be ok? Is having intel i3 going to be a problem for me (2 core), or is it just a RAM issue?

Comment: It's a RAM and processor issue.  It's pretty much impossible for anyone to tell you the exact set up you need to get a certain speed of processing, other than to say that the more RAM you have, and the better the processor you have, the (typically) faster computation you'll have.

Comment: Alright, well that helps a bit. Just thinking about upgrading my laptop in some way. I just dont know if more than 8GB is what I would need, if I need to upgrade to i5 or i7....I mean, if the guy was using 8 cores...I think a quad-core would probably do better than my 2 core. Though I really have no idea.   Im also trying to run: https://github.com/omrysendik/DCor/  which uses matconvnet. It runs, but takes hours to complete instead of 10 minutes.